# AWS v3 + PHP: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Good morning,

I'm working with AWS, to take advantage of the storage service.
I based on version 3, you can find it here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_installation.html
Installing by Using the ZIP file!

I find this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 7: Failed connect to 169.254.169.254:80; No route to host (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))'
```

My code:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
require_once 'aws-autoloader.php';
require_once 'config.php';

$config = array(
        'bucket' => BUCKET,
        'region'  => 'eu-west-3',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials  ' => array('key'=>KEY,
                'secret'=>SECRET)
      );

$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory($config);
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', ['Bucket' => $config['bucket'], 'Prefix' => 'challenge/']
);
```

I'm creating a function independent of cms or framework.

Does anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think you have some whitespace in the 'credentials' key in your array.

`'credentials  ' => array('key'=>KEY,
                'secret'=>SECRET)`

should be

`'credentials' => array('key'=>KEY,
                'secret'=>SECRET)`

Edit: Try updating your credentials to use Aws' credential object

```
$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
$config = array(
    'bucket' => BUCKET,
    'region'  => 'eu-west-3',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials  ' => $credentials
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected. Unfortunately it is not the cause

Comment: Added something else to try, give it a shot :)